# How to get values from NSDictionaries inside an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'd like to know if it's possible to get a values from a desired key inside an `NSDictionary` that is in `NSArray`.

Example:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @{@"title" : @"title 1", @"description" : @"description 1"},
@{@"title" : @"title 2", @"description" : @"description 2"}, 
@{@"title" : @"title 3", @"description" : @"description 3"} ];
```

I'd like to get (without creating a new `NSMutableArray`) all the titles inside my `NSArray`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and my approach is bad altogether.

I know I could create a new class and have 2 properties (title, desc), but is there a way without creating a class or making a new `NSMutableArray` and iterating thorough my array?

Comment: Have you tried getting a reference to the dictionary by calling 'NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];' and then calling dict valueForKey? I don't have the references handy, but it should work.

Comment: The new flashy syntax is not available to iOS developers yet. From the "What's new page":[**Note:** iOS development using literal syntax and object subscripting is not yet implemented.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW1).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is, just requires Xcode 4.4.

Comment: @omz Not according to Apple. I posted a link in the comment above.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Odd, I just tried it and it works fine; I don't even have the iOS 6 SDK installed. Object subscripting wouldn't work, because that requires new methods to be present, but the literal syntax is just a compiler feature and should even work for iOS 4. I would guess that the docs are incorrect there, not sure though.

Comment: Yup, literals work fine in iOS5 with Xcode 4.4. The answer provided by omz is perfect!

Comment: @omz Wow, that's very nice to know, thanks! I guess I shouldn't trust their doc the next time :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Easy:

```
NSArray *titles = [array valueForKey:@"title"];
```

This works because `NSArray`'s implementation of `valueForKey:` returns a new array containing the results of `valueForKey:` for each of the array's objects.

Comment: How to use this feature in `Swift`?